# My .htaccess only works the first time and then gives me error 500

Tags: html, .htaccess, passwords, webserver

For several days I have been trying to set up .htaccess just for one folder I have on my webserver. I would like it to be password protected. It doesn't have to be super secure just has to have some password protection. However it never works. I have tried different versions and even ended up watching some YouTube-videos but still no result. It shows the pop-up window the first time if I try from a webbrowser that I didn't try already. If I clear the cache it will work again the first time and then never again. After having entered my username and password I get error 500. I am not sure what is wrong with my code. I think I should mention that the .htaccess and the .htpasswd are in the same directory because I wanted to make sure that the code is working --> which it isn't. I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Heres my .htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /home/strato/http/power/rid/35/73/51613XXX/htdocs/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

And here's my .htpasswd

```
Aleksandar:$1$3GJ12/5h$IELRGaNF5aE88HE.MkIj40
```

Thanks in advance,

Kind Regards,
Aleksandar

Comment: Check your error log for the details of the error. You'll get a 500 error if it's unable to read the password file for whatever reason. Is this in your document root? What URL are you requesting - the directory only, or a file in that directory? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately my package doesn't support a log. I used a php script to find the current directory. This document is in a folder that I want to lock. I am requesting  a directory. I don't have another .htacces.

Comment: Check the files permissions, make sure that you have enough permissions to read them, seems like the AuthUserFile it's not being properly loaded into the .htaccess.

Comment: "This document is in a folder that I want to lock" - Ok, so it's not the "document root" itself? And you have a subdirectory in the URL-path called `htdocs`? It's just that `htdocs` is a common name for the document root on some distros. If you are not protecting the document root, what is the document root directory? It's just that the filesystem path you are using is a bit "odd looking" (although that doesn't necessarily mean anything).

Comment: Alright, sorry for the late reply. I finally managed to find the problem. Everything was fine except for the path. I didn't realize I was giving the root directory instead of the root directory and its subfolder. After I fixed the path it started working right away. Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: @Aleksandar Thanks for the update. You should put that as an answer (to help other readers and remove the question from the unanswered question queue) - you can later accept it.

Comment: I am not quite understanding what you mean by "unanswered question queue" . I couldn't find that anywhere. Can you explain what you mean by that and where I can do that. Thanks

Comment: You write an "answer" in the answer box below. You can answer your own questions. And you can later "accept" it. The [unanswered question queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Unanswered) is a list of all questions that have no upvoted or accepted answers. Users will look through the "unanswered" question queue looking for questions to answer. You now know the answer to your question, but since an "answer" has not actually been written - it looks like it is still waiting for an answer (which wastes users time who are looking for genuine questions to answer).